# How to define OpenVPN network in haproxy ACLs

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, haproxy

I would like to define OpenVpn network in haproxy ACLs.
OpenVPN server and haproxy is running on the same server (X.X.X.X/32).
It is possible to set up in haproxy to allow requests only from the OpenVPN network? I tried something like this, but it is not working:

```
acl vpnnetwork src 10.10.0.0/16
```

Thanks in Advance

I'm attaching my OpenVPN conf file:

```
port 1194
proto udp6
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh.pem
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/keys
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/keys/ca-crl.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 0
tls-server
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
client-to-client

server 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 5 30
persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nogroup


status openvpn-status.log
status-version 1
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my haproxy cfg what is working for me:

```
frontend http_in
        mode http
        option httplog
        bind *:80       
        option forwardfor

        http-request deny if !{ src 10.10.0.0/16 }

        acl discourse_acl hdr(host) -i discourse.test.com
        use_backend discourse_http if discourse_acl

backend discourse_http
        mode http
        option httplog
        option forwardfor
        server discourse_server 10.115.0.2:8080
```

Domain name `discourse.test.com` needs to point to `10.10.0.1` (IP from VPN network) and `haproxy` should be reloaded. If I connect to VPN then `discourse.test.com:80` is working, without VPN I cannot browse `discourse.test.com`.